# How to work with the output of another ECU

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, port-scanning, diagnostic-tools

I am new in CAPL (CANoe). I have [2 Nodes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fHhn.png); **CAN_Portscanner** that scans a vehicle and returns 47 ECUs and their services and a **Diagnostic Tester** that i want to develop. it has to recognize only a few ECUs from the Portscanner. When I find the service, I need to send a service request to an ECU and extend the ECU function with a response in CANoe to know that my request was successful.

I need to read a message from another .can file and work with it.
I tried something like this:

```
includes
{
  #include "CAN_Portscanner.can"
}

variables
{
  int counter;
}

void MainTest()
{
  while(diagnose_request_msg.ID <= 0x7E1)
  {
    counter++;
  }
  write("Number of ECUs in the Tester: %d",counter);
}
```

I don't know if the #include is correct and why do i obtain a warning about MainTest.

**Warning     2033 at (12,1)**: Use of function 'MainTest' seems to indicate that this file should be a test module or test unit.   Diagnostic Tester.can

Comment: "I have 2 networks here" - According to pic you have two ECU/Nodes not networks.

Comment: What is _the output_ of you CAN_PortScanner? CAN messages? Systemvariables? What is the _input_ of your Diagnostic Tester? CAN ID? ECU Name?
You need to provide much more details...

Comment: @M.Spiller Thank you I added more information

Comment: Still don't have a clue how your _Portscanner_ works, how it collects information, how it stores the information, which information is supposed to be access by the other node...

Comment: in general, the warning is telling you that you should include this function call inside a Test Module. Search for Test Modules and Test Cases in the CANoe user manual or select the MainTest() function and hit F1. You probably don't want to use a Test Case if you are new to CAPL, but rather simpler functions as a sandbox. You can always develop a more refined Test Module later on. Reduce complexity at the beginning ;). The include is correct, although historically "included" CAPL files are .cin and not .can. Functionally it has no effect.